# Cucumber Feature file scenario steps doesn't take me to corresponding step definition when used F3 or Ctrl+click in Java

Tags: java, cucumber-jvm

When I press <kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd></kbd> or <kbd>F3</kbd> on the step in the feature file, to go to step definition, it doesn't take me there.

It just stopped working few days ago and I don't know why. I tried reinstalling “Natural 0.7.6” set of plugins from Marketplace—didn't fix the problem. What am I doing wrong here?!

Moreover, How do I get stuff written in `Feature` tag in Feature file during runtime? `scenario.getId()` returns the Feature filename, i.e., `TestCase01.feature`. However, I want to read “Test Registry Database after CSV files have been Loaded”:

```
Feature: Test Registry Database after CSV files have been Loaded
Scenario: verify_SourceFTP_TableData
        Given XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX     
        When XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
        Then XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
        And XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

pom.xml:

```xml
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-junit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-testng -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: "Moreover, How do I get stuff written in Feature tag in Feature file during runtime??" - is this also a problem that started when the `F3` and `Ctrl+click` functionality stopped working? If not, it should probably be in a question by itself :)

Comment: No. I mean I do not know how to read feature name during run time??

Comment: Hi @Arshad. As I said above: your post is titled "Cucumber Feature file scenario steps doesn't take me to corresponding step definition when used F3 or Ctrl+click in Java". Therefore, your additional question about reading feature information does not belong in *this* question post. You can, and should, ask it in a new, separate post :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I fixed it-

1. Install Cucumber plugin from Eclipse Marketplace if you haven't already [Do not add both Cucumber and Natural plugins at the same time as they seem to clash].
2. Right click the Project Folder in Package Explorer > Configure > Convert to Cucumber project.

This should resolve the issue.

Comment: Thanks a ton mate!! This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is happening when the feature file is opened in the wrong different formate. Please try to open the same file as "Editor" which will be like a chat icon which is the correct formate in that you will get this option by ctrl+click it will take to you step definition